# Select column based on value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large data frame (141k rows), and my goal is to compile a final column based on several others. I need to construct df['Final'] where the value is a slice of column df["A" or "B" or "C" or "D"]. However, I will only know which data to access if I access a different column, here shown as Y. For example:

```
   Z    Y    X    W    A                  B            C           D
1  123  A    456  789  "string:with:data" "other:data" "more:data" "data:more"
2  123  C    456  789  "string:with:data" "other:data" "more:data" "data:more"
3  123  A    456  789  "string:with:data" "other:data" "more:data" "data:more"
```

Basically, to construct my new column, I will only know whether to access A, B, C or D, by reading the cell in Y. Once I know which column to access, the string processing of the data would be the same no matter which is chosen.

Thank you for the help.